# Laravel can't update in database __ the create is working

Tags: php, laravel, controller, insert-update

The problem i have is i click on show on a seperate page then i edit the data.
but when i click on update nothing happen.

**Controller**

```
 public function edit(Request $request,$id)
{
    //
    // $clients = Client::find($client);
    // return view('clients.edit',compact('clients'));
    // ->with('clients', $clients)


    $id = $request->input('id');
    $ClientName = $request->input('ClientName');
    $ClientLastname = $request->input('ClientLastname');
    $ClientCin = $request->input('ClientCin');
    $ClientPhone = $request->input('ClientPhone');

    DB::update('update clients set ClientName = ?,ClientLastname=?,ClientCin=?,ClientPhone=? where id = ?',[$ClientName,$ClientLastname,$ClientCin,$ClientPhone,$id]);

    echo "Record updated successfully.<br/>";
   // echo '<a href = "">Click Here</a> to go back.';
}
 public function update($id)
{


    $clients = DB::select('select * from clients where id = ?',[$id]);
    return view('clients.edit',['clients'=>$clients]);
}
```

***the edit page :***

```
   <form action="{{ route('clients.edit.post',$clients[0]->id) }}" method="POST">

                @csrf
                {{-- @method('PUT') --}}

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input
                        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ID"  id="floatingInput"
                        name="id"
                        value="{{ $clients[0]->id }}"
                        disabled>
                        <label for="floatingInput">Votre ID</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input
                        type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre Prenom"
                        id="floatingInput"
                        name="ClientName"
                        value="{{ $clients[0]->ClientName }}">
                        <label for="floatingInput">Votre Prenom</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre Nom"
                        id="floatingInput"
                        name="ClientLastname"
                        value="{{ $clients[0]->ClientLastname }}">
                        <label for="floatingInput">Votre Nom</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre Cin"
                        id="floatingInput"
                        name="ClientCin"
                        value="{{ $clients[0]->ClientCin }}">
                        <label for="floatingInput">Votre Cin</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Votre Telephone"
                        id="floatingInput"
                        name="ClientPhone"
                        value="{{ $clients[0]->ClientPhone }}">
                        <label for="floatingInput">Votre Telephone</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-4">
                    <button class="btn rounded-pill btn-success ms-2" type="submit">
                        Modifier
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

***the fields on the table:***

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
                                    <a href="{{ route('clients.show', $item->id) }}"
                                        class="btn btn-sm rounded-pill mb-2 btn-info">
                                        Afficher
                                    </a>

                                    <a href='clients/edit/{{ $item->id }}'
                                        class="btn btn-sm rounded-pill btn-warning mb-2">
                                        Modifier
                                    </a>
                                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm rounded-pill btn-danger mb-2"
                                        onclick="return confirm(&quot;Confirm delete?&quot;)">
                                        Supprimer
                                    </button>
                                </form>
```

***The routes :***

```
Route::get('receptions/clients/edit',[ClientController::class ,'edit'])->name('clients.edit');
Route::get('receptions/clients/edit/{id}',[ClientController::class ,'update'])->name('clients.update');
Route::post('receptions/clients/edit/{id}',[ClientController::class ,'edit'])->name('clients.edit.post');
```

Comment: Do you get the `Record updated successfully` message with no database update, or nothing at all? Does it attempt to submit the form?

Comment: yes i do get `the record updated successfully` message but with no database update.

Comment: One thing you can try to do is add this right above your update:  `Log::info("update clients set ClientName =$ClientName,ClientLastname=$ClientLastname,ClientCin=$ClientCin,ClientPhone=$ClientPhone where id = $id");`. Then check your Laravel logs in `storage/logs` to see what is being sent to the database. You can also [assign the return value of the update function to a variable](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-an-update-statement), and either log it or add it to the returned string to show the number of affected records.

Comment: It's Working now thank you.
i went to the `storage/logs` and i  found that the `id` is not there
so the problem was from the input of the id there was `disabled`

Comment: I appreciate it man 
i didn't knew about that `storage/log` 
will work with that from now on to check
thank you again.

Comment: No problem. I adore and abuse the logging function in Laravel. It's great for tracking down issues and tracking the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Better way:

```
DB::table('clients')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
      'ClientName' => $ClientName,
      'ClientLastname' => $ClientLastname,
      'ClientCin' => $ClientCin,
      'ClientPhone' => $ClientPhone
    ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#update-statements